# How to delete postgres database within docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to figure out how to completely remove a docker container with a postgres database and rebuild using docker-compose?

I created a server and database container using docker-compose. The database did not get set up how I wanted, so I would like to remove the database and rebuild. I assumed the easiest solution, given it is brand new would be to stop the container from running, remove the container and then run docker-compose again.

I have followed those steps, do not see any of the containers. I do not see any volumes associated with the containers. However, when I run docker-compose it appears to be using the postgres database that was previously created?

Here is what my docker-compose files consists of with user/password/db name extracted.

```
services:
  server:
    image: "node:10"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    command: "npm start"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: [user] 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: [password]
      POSTGRES_DB: [db_name]
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I expected that by using:

`docker stop [container]` to stop the container, then
`docker rm [container]` to remove the container

I could rebuild fresh with `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Docker stop` and `docker rm` will not work untill you remove bind mount volume from your `docker-compose`.

Remove this from your docker-compose

```
     - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

or delete everything from host directory inside

```
./data/postgres
```

Comment: I deleted the information from `./data/postres` , which for my situation was ideal.

Comment: This article was also helpful to get more of an understanding on how docker is handling volumes set up within compose:  https://www.linux.com/tutorials/docker-volumes-and-networks-compose/

Answer (score 15):

You can list the volumes used by docker with this command:

```
docker volume ls
```

Then, if needed, you can inspect the volumes to find which one your database uses:

```
docker volume inspect xyzvolumename
```

After locating the volume used by your database, delete it for a fresh start:

```
docker volume rm locatedvolumename
```